# Enable Django View CSFR protection for anonymous Python clients using API requests (rather than templates)

Tags: django

Some Views in my Django 11.1 application get requested by both GUI Templates (user must login for access), and by anonymous python client apps executed as a CLI program (no login). 
I needed to enable CSFR protection for all Views, but this protection requires a session id to work (without as session, CSFR attack wouldn't work anyway).

I came up with the solutions shown bellow, but would like to know if there is a better way of doing it.

**Solution for GUI templates**: This is rather simple and well documented [in Django docs. Just include {% csrf_token %}  between POST tags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/csrf/#how-to-use-it).

**Solution for Python clients (anonymous)**: This solution is not clearly documented in the docs (or perhaps it is, but I didn't find an easy step by step instruction). So this is what I did:

1. In globals.py:

   ```
   MIDDLEWARE = [
   'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
   'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
   'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
   'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
   ```
2. Create a Django View that returns a CSFR token and a session ID for anonymous clients:

   ```
   from django.middleware.csrf import get_token
   ...
   csfr_token = get_token(request)
   ...      
   if not request.session.session_key:        
       request.session.create()        
   ....
   return JsonResponse({'token': csfr_token, 'sessionid' : request.session.session_key})
   ```
3. The anonymous client, first requests the token and session ID with a GET:

   ```
   ...
   myrequest = urllib.request.Request(url_to_the_django_view, method='GET')
   myresponse = urllib.request.urlopen(myrequest )
   myresponse _read = eval(myresponse.read())
   return myresponse _read['token'], myresponse _read['sessionid']
   ```
4. Lastly, send a post request with CSFR information in the POST form and in HTTP header:

   ```
   ...
   req.add_header('X-CSRFToken', token)        
   req.add_header('Cookie', 'csrftoken=' + token + ';' + 'sessionid=' + sessionid)
   ...        
   urllib.request.urlopen(req)
   ...
   ```

Comment: I am not sure that i understand - does your app run on a server in-house and you want the login/session stuff for people from the outside world, and in-house you have multiple computers running your app locally and don't want to have logins?

Comment: Clients and server are in-house (a large network). The clients app can be a CLI apps(running from linux hosts) or GUI apps (running on the browser, from the users' workstation). The GUI apps will login.